# PySimpleGUI - How to get table row data on click

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a two tables in a tabgroup and want to get the row informations by clicking on the row. i cant get it to work. Can anybody help me?

I want the selected informatons from the row to put into an input field. I gave the table an key, but i'm not able to get the infos. If i click on the table within the tabgroup nothing happens

```
layout_buy_package_table    = [

                        [
                            sg.Table(
                                values=package_data_all,
                                headings=headings_pakete,
                                max_col_width=35,
                                auto_size_columns=True,
                                display_row_numbers=True,
                                justification="left",
                                num_rows=15,
                                key="-TABLE_BUY_PACKAGES-",
                                row_height=30,
                                background_color="#272533",
                                text_color="white",
                                enable_events=True
                            ),
                            sg.Text("Paketpreis", size=10, background_color="#272533", text_color="white", pad=(20)),
                            sg.Input(size=15, key="-INDIVIDUAL_BUY_PRICE-", enable_events=True),
                            sg.Button("Paket erstellen", button_color=("black", "darkorange"), size=(12, 1))
                        ]
                    ]
                    layout_sell_package_table = [

                        [
                            sg.Table(
                                values=sell_package_data,
                                headings=headings_sell_pakete,
                                max_col_width=35,
                                auto_size_columns=True,
                                display_row_numbers=True,
                                justification="left",
                                num_rows=15,
                                key="-TABLE_SELL_PACKAGES-",
                                row_height=30,
                                background_color="#272533",
                                text_color="white",
                                enable_events=True
                            ),
                            sg.Text("Paketpreis", size=10, background_color="#272533", text_color="white", pad=(20)),
                            sg.Input(size=15, key="-INDIVIDUAL_SELL_PRICE-", enable_events=True),
                            sg.Button("Paket erstellen", button_color=("black", "darkorange"), size=(12, 1))
                        ]

                    ]

                    tab_group_packages = [
                        [
                            sg.TabGroup(
                                [
                                    [
                                        sg.Tab("Pakete - Kauforder", layout_buy_package_table, background_color="#272533")
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        sg.Tab("Pakete Verkauforder", layout_sell_package_table, background_color="#272533")
                                    ]

                                ],
                                tab_background_color="darkorange",
                                enable_events=True
                            )
                        ],
                        [
                            sg.Button("Alle erstellen", button_color=("black", "green"), size=(20, 2)),
                            sg.Button("Abbrechen", button_color=("black", "red"), size=(20, 2))
                        ]
                    ]

                    window_package_table = sg.Window("Paketübersicht", tab_group_packages, background_color="#272533")
                    while True:
                        event, window_package_table.read()
                        if event == "-TABLE_BUY_PACKAGES-":
                            print("Test")
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing, it is caused by the wrong statement in your event loop.

```py
    event, window_package_table.read()
```

It should be something like this

```py
while True:

    event, values = window_package_table.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    # print(event, values)
    if event == "-TABLE_BUY_PACKAGES-":
        index = values[event][0]
        print(package_data_all[index])
    elif event == '-TABLE_SELL_PACKAGES-':
        index = values[event][0]
        print(sell_package_data[index])

window_package_table.close()
```